# Dúvida sobre conceitos de Sistemas Operacionais é on-topic?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Direto ao ponto: dúvida conceitual de sistemas operacionais é on-topic? Temos perguntas com a tag [sistemas-operacionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sistemas-operacionais) que foram bem-recebidas, por exemplo sobre o problema dos Filósofos Glutões (que talvez não caia no mesmo caso).

[Como o kernel do sistema operacional é acordado para executar o algoritmo de escalonamento Shortest Job First preemptivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/509384/357)

Talvez esta não seja porque não é relacionada diretamente à programação, mas pode ser (comportamento do escalonador afeta a priorização dos processos e a execução do código).

Como vocês veem essa questão?

Comment: A pergunta tem muitos pressupostos que não sei avaliar por ignorância do assunto, mas não me parece fora do escopo. Entendo que possa ser melhorada, mas estaria no escopo do site sim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De forma geral é sim, quando envolve programação deles, ou algo que é usado em programação. Tem que ser conceito mesmo, não pode ser uso do sistema operacional. Como fazer um sistema operacional ou como funciona é um conceito da computação, tem até disciplina nos bons cursos.

Daí a ser uma boa pergunta depende de como ela é feita.

O exemplo específico é complicado embora eu classificaria como *on* por ser algo que se estudo formalmente na computação. Porém eu não sei se a pergunta é muito bem feita, ela dá um pouco de margem para interpretação. Eu tenho um pouco de dificuldade de classificá-la, presaria de mais opinião.

Comment: Certo, concordamos que em geral é on-topic mas poderia ser melhorada. Nesse caso deixaria fechada mesmo, só que pelo motivo errado. O que se faz nesse caso, compensa deixar assim então, ou reabrir para em seguida fechar de novo pelo motivo certo? Ou só esta discussão que estamos tendo, linkada à pergunta, basta para esclarecer a situação de fechamento da mesma?

Comment: @Piovezan tem ainda outra alternativa: melhorar a pergunta para que entre na fila de votação para reabrir. Acho que é a melhor opção, já que aparentemente o pessoal gostou da pergunta e concordou que poderia ser melhor.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Por ser ambígua é complicado outra pessoa além do AP melhorar, acho eu. Porque só ele sabe o que quer perguntar. E eu confesso que não tenho domínio do assunto suficiente para deduzir o que pode ser (tenho um palpite, mas é só). :)

Comment: Agora vi que o autor removeu a pergunta. Pena :/